# PowerLevel10K prompt not getting correctly formatted in tmux

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, tmux, oh-my-zsh

I am using `oh-my-zsh` shell and `powerlevel10k` theme on my system. I recently installed `tmux`. But for some reason the prompt of tmux is not getting correctly formatted.

Here is my `.tmux.conf` file:

```
set -g default-terminal "xterm-256color"
bind-key -r Space next-layout
set -g status-bg black
set -g status-fg white
set -g mouse on
```

prompt in tmux: [in tmux]

[image]

prompt outside tmux in normal shell: [outside tmux]

[image]

It will be great, if anyone can help.

Answer (score 4):

tmux replaces non-ascii symbols with `_` if it was started without `-u` option and the locale at the time of its start wasn't UTF-8. The best way to fix this issue is to install and enable an UTF-8 locale on your system. Alternatively, you can start tmux with `-u` option.

There is an additional problem in your tmux config. From `man tmux`:

> `default-terminal` *terminal*
>
> Set the default terminal for new windows created in this session - the default value of the TERM environment variable.  For tmux to work correctly, this must be set to ‘screen’, ‘tmux’ or a derivative of them.

In your config `default-terminal` is set to `xterm-256color`. This is neither `screen`, nor `tmux`, nor a derivative of them. Hence tmux won't work correctly.

To fix this issue, replace `xterm-256color` in `~/.tmux.conf` with `screen-256color` and reboot your machine. You can force tmux to reload without rebooting but rebooting will definitely do it.

Comment: Doesn't help. By the way if I change the default shell to bash, then there is no formatting error, formatting error occurs with powerlevel10k zsh theme

Comment: `set -g default-terminal "screen-256color"` works..

Comment: The `-u` option **worked** for me, thanks. Tested on macOS Ventura version 13.6 with iTerm2 build 3.4.20, Powerlevel10k version 1.19.0.